# cant find /_layouts/AreaTemplateSettings.aspx

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, spweb, template

I try to save my spweb as template but i dont have this page on my site how can I get it , even my web is  a publishing site)

my template site is :CMSPUBLISHING #39

Comment: "Save as template" is NOT available once the Publishing feature has been activated

Comment: SO , what is the solution to save publishing site as temlpate

Answer (score 3):

here is a solution for publishSites:

1. Open the publishing site in SharePoint Designer 2013.
2. Click the Site Settings icon on the ribbon. SiteOptions_in_SPD
3. Modify the parameter SaveSiteAsTemplateEnabled from the default value of false to true.

   [Saving Publishing Site as a Template in SharePoint 2013](https://wmostafaw.wordpress.com/2013/05/16/saving-publishing-site-as-a-template-in-sharepoint-2013/)

Comment: That will allow you to save, yes. But it will not necessarily enable you to create a site from the template again

Comment: Link you have specified here is not working

Comment: Robert , you are right , it doesnt allow me , error : $Resources:ReportServerResources,DataSourceContentTypeName; » ne peut pas contenir les caractères suivants : \  / : * ? " # % < > { } | ~ &, deux points consécutifs (..)